# MVC 4 Why is My Website Keep Redirecting me to Account/Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

My program was working before. I do not know what changes did I make, but now suddenly my login behaves so weird. Every time I try to access Admin authorized page, it keeps redirecting me to login page, even after I login. Here is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(AlvinCMSExtension.Models.LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        string redirectUrl = returnUrl;
        string userName = model.UserName;
        AlvinCMSExtension.Models.UserProfile user = dbAccount.UserProfiles.Where(m => m.Email.Equals(userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            userName = user.UserName;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(userName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LoginRedirectionControl", new { redirectUrl = redirectUrl });
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult LoginRedirectionControl(string redirectUrl)
    {
        string returnUrl = redirectUrl;
        if (redirectUrl == null)
        {
            redirectUrl = User.IsInRole("Admin") ? "/Admin" : "/";
        }
        return RedirectToLocal(redirectUrl);
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Page");

    }
```

And I tried to access this:

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

After each successful login, the `Redirect(returnUrl)` does not take me to the returnUrl, but instead to login page again. The parameter used is: `http://localhost:5847/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2fDashboard`. I debug the code and the returnUrl is holding `/Admin/Dashboard/`. I do not know what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the user has the role "Admin", it may be removed

Comment: This is so silly of me. I do not know what was happened but yeah, the userinrole was removed. I did not thought of this, i thought it was something with the iis server. Thanks